# How exploitable are cache timing attacks?

Tags: timing-attack

So there's a recent PHP package that has been written to protect against cache timing attacks, which [can be seen here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/4a1iuh/rfc_4648_character_encoding_written_to_resist/)
.

My question is...  just how exploitable are cache timing attacks?

My overall impression is that they're extremely difficult to exploit and attempting to protect against them is rather like using a 1MB two-prime RSA key instead of a 2KB two-prime RSA key to protect against factorization - that it is unnecessary and impractical

Comment: Well, the attack scenario is already quite restrictive: You have to sit on the same CPU as your victim for the attack to work...

Comment: @SEJPM It's of course a good question if you should consider that "quite restrictive" in the age of people running VM's in the cloud... Share and enjoy :) I'd of course question any code that uses base 32 or base 64 to encode secret values in the first place (*before* wrapping them).

Comment: @SEJPM Have you ever kept a browser tab with javascript enabled open for several days? Then you may be vulnerable to [this javascript-based cache attack](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.07373.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

An important article from last month on ZDNet shows that [cache timing attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/41680/) can be very exploitable.

Researchers at Vrije University in Amsterdam announced a new side-channel attack on Intel CPUs called **NetCAT**.  From [the article on ZDNet](https://www.zdnet.com/article/intel-server-grade-cpus-impacted-by-new-netcat-attack/):

> Named NetCAT, this is a vulnerability in all Intel chips that support
>   the Data-Direct I/O Technology (Intel DDIO) and Remote Direct Memory
>   Access (RDMA) features.
>
> When these two features are enabled, academics have shown that they
>   can launch an attack on remote, networked computers, and infer certain
>   types of data that is being processed inside the CPU's cache.

To emphasize: the attacker **does not need physical access** to the device.

> VUSec academics have shown that sending carefully crafted network
>   packets to a DDIO-capable CPU allows an attacker to keep an eye on
>   what else is being processed in the CPU.

In short, **NetCAT allows keylogging,** and the attacker can even [predict the words that will be typed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXut1XBymAk&feature=youtu.be) from an SSH session.